# How do I find these confidence intervals?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I am looking to calculate confidence intervals for the following:

If $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid following $N(\mu,\mu^2)$

How do I set about calculating confidence intervals for these pivots:

- $\frac{\bar{X}}{\mu}$ where $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean
- $\frac{1}{\mu}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|X_i-\bar{X}|$

I have worked out that the distribution of $\bar{X}$ is $N(1,1/n)$ but I don't know how to use this to calculate $a_1$ and $a_2$ in the equation

$P(\frac{\bar{X}}{a_2}<\mu<\frac{\bar{X}}{a_1})=0.95$

Am I along the right lines?

Comment: The distribution of $\bar{X}$ is  $N(\mu,\mu^2/n)$ while the distribution of $\frac{\bar{X}}{\mu}$ is $N(1,1/n)$

Comment: Meanwhile the distributions of $X_i-\bar{X}$ are $N(0,\mu^2(n-1)/n)$, though summing the absolute values is not straightforward

Comment: So how would I go about finding $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Comment: Can you find $L$ and $U$ such that $P(L < \bar X/\mu < U) = .95)$ and manipulate the inequality?

Comment: But then L and U have infinitely many possibilities surely?

Comment: Can you please try answering a similar question [here] as I am stuck for days (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909908/why-sampling-without-replacement-gives-better-ci-performance)